# How to jump to #id anchor bewteen different fullpage.js scroll sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I wanted to know whether it is possible to 
scroll to #id anchor/bookmark bewteen two different fullpage.js scroll sections?

We know by initializing

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors:['firstSection', 'secondSection'],
    animateAnchor: true
});
```

When we visit http://fullpageexample.com/#secondSection 
it scrolls all the way to the target anchor section untill it stops.

But if there are lot of articles inside the secondSection, 
and the requirement is to build up a link like

```
<a href="article2-in-section2" >jump button</a>
```

and move focus directly to the anchor, where the

```
<div id="article2-in-section2"></div>
```

is located inside another scrolling section initialized by fullpage.js

Is it achievable without breaking the fullpage.js effect ? 
(there are callback functions avaialbe, 
  but I didn't see it so simple to hook into callbacks for moving focus to #id)

```
afterLoad (anchorLink, index)
onLeave (index, nextIndex, direction)
```

jsfiddle show page: http://jsfiddle.net/7PwsS/973/show/

jsfiddle edit: http://jsfiddle.net/7PwsS/973/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, it is not possible, and less yet if you don't use `scrollBar:true`.